# How to parse T date format in Android?

Tags: android, simpledateformat

I am working on date format application, i have one T date format but i am not able to parse this format.

```
try {
     String dtStart = "2016-07-20T11:51:31.744Z";

     SimpleDateFormat format = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss'Z'");

       if (dtStart != null) {
          Date date = format.parse(dtStart);

          Calendar myCal = new GregorianCalendar();
          myCal.setTime(date);

          String promoPendingDay = "" + myCal.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH);
          int promoPendingMonth = myCal.get(Calendar.MONTH) + 1;
          String promoPendingYear = "" + myCal.get(Calendar.YEAR);

          mMessageStartDateLabel.setText(promoPendingDay + "/" + promoPendingMonth + "/" + promoPendingYear);
       }

} catch (ParseException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

every time i am getting one exception `java.text.ParseException: Unparseable date:`

Please kindly go through my code and suggest me some solution.

Comment: you have milliseconds as well.

Comment: hey thanks i am little confuse in this format can you please tell me how to parse this date format

Comment: add `.SSS` after `ss`

Comment: hey thanks it worked

Answer (score 0):

Here a solution applying two changes. One change is to add the fractional seconds, another change is to set the UTC-timezone.

```
SimpleDateFormat format = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSS'Z'");
format.setTimeZone(TimeZone.getTimeZone("GMT")); // very important, input Z means UTC+00
```